# if a number is not prime number then we have to print out whta number it is divisible by

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class exam2015q2
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Eneter a number");
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        int num1 = num-1;
        int count = 0;

        if(num % 2 == 0)
        {

            count++;

            System.out.println(+num+ " Is an even number");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(num+" Is an odd number");
        }

        boolean isPrime = true;

        do {

            if(num % num1 == 0)
            {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
            num1--;
        }
        while(num1 >= 2);
        if(isPrime == true)
        {
            System.out.println(num +" is a prime number  as it is only divisible by 1 and " +num);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(num +" is NOT a prime number.It is divisible by " +count);

        }
    }
}
```

in this i need to output if its not a prime number then we have to output what number it is divisible by but i cant get that to print it out. i need help on this can someone give me suggestions on how to get the number for divisible by

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) and 
[Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6166/989)

Comment: cool bro this is not a howrk question btw its an exam question

Comment: Never use code  with (isPrime == true). The reason you use booleans is to avoid the need for comparisons since the comparison has already been done.

Comment: omg no i was wondering how do u print out what number it is divisible by if its not a prime number

Comment: how do u do that in the code

Comment: you need any one number by whom non prime number is divisible? Right?

Comment: If the number is not a prime number you need to go through single digits and modulus operator that with the digit, and check to see if it returns 0.

Comment: yes Mr ramzan just one number that is divisible by it

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Eneter a number");
        int divisibleBy;
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        int num1 = num-1;
        int count=0;

        if(num%2==0)
        {
            count++;
            System.out.println(+num+ " Is an even number");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(num+" Is an odd number");
        }
        boolean isPrime = true;
        do{
            if(num%num1==0)
            {
                divisibleBy = num1;
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
            num1--;
        }
        while(num1>=2);
        if(isPrime == true)
        {
               System.out.println(num +" is a prime number  as it is only divisible by 1 and " +num);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(num +" is NOT a prime number.It is divisible by " +divisibleBy);



 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your statement showing the variable the number is divisible by from `count` to `num1`, since you determine in your `do` loop that `num` can be divided by `num1` already.

```
else{
    System.out.println(num +" is NOT a prime number.It is divisible by " +num1);
}
```

You can get rid of `count` entirely in your program as it is shown.